# Calculate balance from Credit and Debit records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following records in my database table:

```
Date            Credit  Debit      Description
--------------- ------- -------    ---------------
12-24-2015      5                  Purchased credit
12-20-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-15-2015      3                  Purchased credit
12-08-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-08-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-07-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-04-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-03-2015              1          Consumed credit
12-01-2015      5                  Purchased credit
```

I want to calculate and display the balance for each record as shown below:

```
Date         Credit  Debit   Balance  Description
------------ ------- ------- -------  ---------------
12-24-2015   5       0       7        Purchased credit
12-20-2015           1       2        Consumed credit
12-15-2015   3       0       3        Purchased credit
12-08-2015           1       0        Consumed credit
12-08-2015           1       1        Consumed credit
12-07-2015           1       2        Consumed credit
12-04-2015           1       3        Consumed credit
12-03-2015           1       4        Consumed credit
12-01-2015   5       0       5        Purchased credit
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve the above result?

Comment: It is already posted in the question. First section shows the available data and the second shows the expected result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To produce balance use `sum()` in analytical version.

```
select tdate, credit, debit, 
       sum(nvl(credit, 0)-nvl(debit, 0)) over (order by rn) balance, description
  from (
    select tdate, credit, debit, row_number() over (order by tdate) rn, description 
      from test)
  order by rn desc
```

If your table contains increasing primary key you can use this instead of generated row number.

Test data and output:

```
create table test (tdate date, credit number(6), debit number(6), description varchar2(20));
insert into test values (date '2015-12-24', 5, null, 'Purchased credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-20', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-15', 3, null, 'Purchased credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-08', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-08', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-07', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-04', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-03', null, 1, 'Consumed credit');
insert into test values (date '2015-12-01', 5, null, 'Purchased credit');

TDATE        CREDIT   DEBIT    BALANCE DESCRIPTION
----------- ------- ------- ---------- --------------------
2015-12-24        5                  7 Purchased credit
2015-12-20                1          2 Consumed credit
2015-12-15        3                  3 Purchased credit
2015-12-08                1          0 Consumed credit
2015-12-08                1          1 Consumed credit
2015-12-07                1          2 Consumed credit
2015-12-04                1          3 Consumed credit
2015-12-03                1          4 Consumed credit
2015-12-01        5                  5 Purchased credit
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `LAG` analytic function for this to look at the previous row's data.

```
SELECT Date, 
       Credit, 
       Debit, 
       LAG(Balance, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY Date) - Debit + Credit AS Balance, 
       Description
  FROM sometable
```

The `1` argument means that it looks 1 row previous, the `0` argument means if the row at the given offset doesn't exist it will return 0 instead (i.e. for the first row).

Source: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: I don't believe that's an issue, since the Credit is being added to that 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first do a self-join, then list out the results in order as:

```
SELECT a1.Date, a1.Debit, a1.Credit, SUM(a2.Debit-a2.Credit) Balance, Description
FROM table a1, table a2
WHERE a1.debit<=a2.debit and a1.credit<=a2.credit OR (a1.debit=a2.debit and a1.credit=a2.credit and a1.date = a2.date)
GROUP BY a1.Date, a1.Debit, a1.Credit
ORDER BY a1.Date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

for whom may see this question for `mssql`, you can use this query:

```
select tdate, credit, debit, 
       sum(isnull(credit, 0)-isnull(debit, 0)) over (order by rn) balance, description
  from (
    select tdate, credit, debit, row_number() over (order by tdate) rn, description 
      from test)
  order by rn desc
```